# Convert Boolean to number in xml

Tags: xml, orbeon

I'm going to convert boolean to number in XML (orbeon), and I'm using number in the formula but still it's showing boolean type.

This is my formula, I'm using round but still showing true:

round(seconds($total-time-calculation-mental)div 60 ) or round(seconds($control-2)div 60)

#Orbeon

Answer (score 2):

This is really an XPath question rather than an XML or orbeon question.

The XPath "or" operator expects two booleans as input, and produces a boolean as output: TRUE or FALSE => TRUE. The numbers you've supplied as input are converted to booleans (0 = FALSE, anything else = TRUE), but there's no reason for the result to be converted back.

What did you actually expect this expression to return?

Perhaps you were using "or" incorrectly in a construct like (A = 5 or 6) to mean (A = 5 or A = 6)?

Or perhaps you had the Javascript usage in mind, where A || B means "if A exists then return A, otherwise return B"?

Comment: if (round(seconds($total-time-calculation-mental) div 60) > 0) then round(seconds($total-time-calculation-mental) div 60) else round(seconds($control-2) div 60) This is the piece of code which I'm using but it only calculates $total-time-calculation-mental and it completely ignores $control-2

Comment: You need to supply a complete example in which we can see the values of the variables. If the condition is true then we would expect $control-2 to be ignored. You're still showing us code that doesn't work, and expecting us to guess what your incorrect code was supposed to do.